# Datediff and pivot

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this table (actual table is much larger):

```
id     class     startdate      enddate    
----------------------------------------
1       High       1/1/15       2/1/15      
1       Low        5/1/15       6/1/15      
1       Mid        6/1/15       6/10/15
```

Is there a way to produce results like the below...

```
 id  High    Mid    low
 -----------------------
 1    30      9      30
```

My work below...(just showing that I'm trying to work through this)

```
SELECT DISTINCT   --DATEDIFF(DAY, tt.START_DATE,tt.END_DATE)AS Stay_days, 
    tt.[high], tt.[mid], tt.[low], tt.id,
FROM            
  (SELECT 
       [pvt_High], [pvt_mid], [pvt_low], pvt.STARTDATE, pvt.ENDDATE, pvt.id
   FROM 
       (SELECT DISTINCT   
            l.id, L.class, l.STARTDATE, l.ENDDATE,
            DATEDIFF(DAY, l.STARTDATE, l.ENDDATE) AS STAY_DAYS,
            'Y' AS Flag
        FROM TEST l
        WHERE 1=1

        PIVOT (MAX(Flag) FOR CLASS IN ([pvt_HIGH], [pvt_MID],[pvt_LOW]))
        AS pvt
    ) tt
```

Comment: Maybe a self join with and class = each category, not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inner select to get the data into a form where you have the id, class and number of days.  Then you can pivot that on the class value into columns.

```
select *
from
(
    select id, class, datediff(day, startDate, endDate) as days
    from @test
) x
pivot
(
    max(days) for class in (high, low, med)
) y
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/7161)

Obviously change the names, etc to appropriate things for your data, this is just an example.

Comment: But does the above scrip account for three seperate startdate and enddates?

Comment: @MrJohn Yup. Check out the fiddle I linked to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure where I went wrong but thanks for the answer! I'm thinking I has my pivot script incorrect.

Comment: Just trying to figure out where I went wrong in my script. Could it be I had max(flag) and not max(days)?

Comment: @MrJohn That looks like that was at least part of it.  Since `flag` was just 'Y' for every row, it was going to pick that value for each pivot column.  Also, not using the other columns like `stay_days` probably screwed it up too, since it implicitly groups by the columns not specified in the pivot..